# What should I be paying for a dedicated server and what features should I make sure I get?

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting

I am based in the UK and need a new web server for a small ecommerce site. It is not big enough to need separate database and web servers, so everything will sit happily on a single machine.

I have been getting a few quotes, but thought I would see what people think is reasonable for a low to medium spec dedicated server (Linux)?

If you were ordering a new server today, what features would you want from the hardware and the hosting company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the requirements of the business.  If uptime isn't paramount, you can get away with a basic system with no redundancy, just make sure you have a backup and a known-working plan to restore it.  For example, I have two servers with SoftLayer here in the United States.  One is in Dallas, and one is in Seattle.  They each run about $120/mo with Windows.  Their Linux servers are cheaper, but the hardware is the same.  Basically a single processor, 1GB of RAM, and a single SATA hard drive around 250GB (way more than I need for my purposes).  Prices vary and go up from there.  Expect to pay extra if you need features like having them handle backups, hardware firewalls, etc.  You can get a virtual private server for less, but I've found that full dedicated servers are generally more reliable (in my own experience anyway).